# proof / disproof of context-free language

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

Given the following language:
$$
L = \{b^n \mid \text{$n$ is prime} \}\cup \{b^n \mid \text{$n$ is even}\}
$$
Need to proof or disproof whether this language is context-free or not.

I know that only prime numbers is not context-free, but not sure what happens with the following union..any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We know that if $L_1$ is context-free and $L_2$ is regular, then : $L_1 \cap L_2$ is context-free.

It's easy to see that $\{b^n \mid \text{n is odd}\}$ is regular. ({b}.{bb}*)

Let's assume that $L$ is context-free.

Then $$L \cap \{b^n \mid \text{n is odd}\} = \{b^n \mid n \neq 2 \land\text{n is prime}\}$$
It is easy to show that the resulting language is not context-free (it's the same as without the $n\neq2$.)

There is the contradiction. The resulting language is not context-free. Then $L$ is not context-free.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Consider the language $L \cap \{b^n \mid \text{$n$ is odd}\}$.